# cbind 2nd element of list of lists together

Tags: r, list, lapply, cbind

I have data like the biglist example below, which is a list of 2 lists of 2.  I would like to `cbind` the second list from each list together like the result example below.  Normally, I would try something like `lapply(biglist,cbind)` but I'm not sure how to do that with a list of lists.

```
Data:
dput(biglist)
list(list(list(1, 2, 3), list(5, 4, 6)), list(list(5, 9, 2), 
list(4, 6, 1)))

Result:
dput(result)
structure(list(4, 6, 1, 5, 4, 6), .Dim = c(3L, 2L)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, something like this ?

```
matrix(unlist(lapply(bigList, function(x) x[2])), ncol = length(bigList))

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    5    4
#[2,]    4    6
#[3,]    6    1
```

From every list taking the second element and then `unlist`ing the list and converting it into a matrix where number of columns (`ncol`) would be the `length` of the list.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another version with `mapply`

```
mapply(`[[`, biglist, 2)
#   [,1] [,2]
#[1,] 5    4   
#[2,] 4    6   
#[3,] 6    1
```

Answer (score 2):

With purrr, you could do

```
library(purrr)

bigList %>% map(2) %>% invoke(cbind, .)
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,] 5    4   
## [2,] 4    6   
## [3,] 6    1
```

or the base R equivalent:

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(bigList, `[[`, 2))
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,] 5    4   
## [2,] 4    6   
## [3,] 6    1
```

or, as it happens, that's how `sapply` simplifies:

```
sapply(bigList, `[[`, 2)
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,] 5    4   
## [2,] 4    6   
## [3,] 6    1
```

The idea regardless of grammar is to extract the second element of each sublist, then pass that list as the parameters to `cbind` (well, really `simplify2array` within `sapply`). If you want the columns reversed as the desired result suggests, chuck a `rev` in there before the `cbind`.

Answer (score 2):

Related to ronak-shah's method, you could use `vapply` which simplifies output automatically producing a matrix.

```
vapply(bigList, function(i) unlist(i[[2]]), FUN.VALUE=numeric(3))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    4
[2,]    4    6
[3,]    6    1
```